# What's a good German translation for ".. you'll be such a bad loser"?

Tags: adjective, german-to-english

The English sentence is:

> If you do something like that, you'll be such a bad* loser.

Meaning that you'll lose badly.

I translated it as:

> ... Du bist ja ein schlechter Verlierer.

But someone told me, don't use "schlechter" but "guter" instead. Who's a "schlechter Verlierer" and who is a "guter" one? Is there a better translation for what I'm trying to say?

<sub>*: What I meant is not that the person as a bad loser, becomes angry when they lose but preventing them from doing it by using the word "bad".</sub>

Comment: As an aside, the English translation for the German "schlechter Verlierer" (somebody who can't stand losing, and will get angry or start arguing when doing so) is "sore loser".

Comment: I think your English sentence doesn't mean what you want it to mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the meaning you added in your footnote "*schlechter Verlierer*" is not the appropriate translation. Let me give you some interchangeable variations on how to say what you meant (translations for *"bad"* in italic):

> Wenn Du so etwas machst, wirst Du *übel* verlieren.
>   Es wird *böse* enden, wenn Du dies machst.
>   Wenn Du so weiter machst, wird das *schlecht* ausgehen.
>   Dein Vorhaben wird ein *schlimmes* Ende nehmen.
>   Du bist ein *elender* Versager, wenn Du das machst.

The last example is quite strong and as such may be considered as rude.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean "to lose badly".

> Wenn du so etwas machst, dann wird das **übel** für dich ausgehen.
>
> "Übel"

In that sense it means a bad outcome and "für dich ausgehen" puts emphasis on the personal consequences.

Answer (score 3):

"You will" be is future tense, So that can't match "Du bist", which is present time.

> Wenn Du das tust, wirst Du schrecklich (furchtbar, übel,
>   schlimm, empfindlich, haushoch (v.a. im Sport)) verlieren!

I guess it is a recent development, to brand somebody "Verlierer" or "Loser" in German:

> Wenn Du das tust, wirst Du ein Verlierer sein.

"Schlechter Verlierer" is the terminology for a person who cannot stand losing a battle, a fight or a game. So you would avoid such attributes to emphasize the meaning, as you mentioned yourself.

Comment: One should add, that in colloquial german the future tense often gets replaced by the present, even if you talk about a specific point of time in the future.

Comment: @0x6d64: Exactly, that's why I used "sein".I thought "werden" means "would" and no one would be a loser!

Comment: In der Form "Wenn ..., dann bist Du ein Verlierer" ja. Oder "..., dann hast Du verloren!". Wie in der Fragestellung präsentiert haben die Sätze aber wenig gemeinsam.